# Open URL in current tab in Firefox via Applescript

Tags: firefox, applescript

I use this script to open a URL in a new tab but I would like it to open in the current tab instead. Is there a way to do this?

```
tell application "Firefox"
    open location "http://www.yubnub.org"
end tell
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox's Applescript support appears not very existent.

Try this workaround using System Events and key strokes.

```
tell application "Firefox"
    activate
    set the clipboard to "http://www.yubnub.org"
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "l" using {command down}
        keystroke "v" using {command down}
        key code 36 -- return key
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked and it is exactly what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted the accepted answer, it's great and led me to my solution, but using the clipboard to enter the URL seems unnecessary when you can simply send the URL via keys

```
tell application "Firefox"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "l" using {command down}
        keystroke "http://www.yubnub.org"
        key code 36 -- return key
    end tell
end tell
```

A line shorter, more understandable, and doesn't have the unwanted side effect of overwriting your clipboard.